# Immutable change array of object inside array of objects state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, immutability

I have an array of objects(cards) inside array of objects(wid) which is inside object(data) like this:

```json
{
  data: {
    ban: {
      first: "one"
    },
    foo: {
      second: "two"
    },
    wid: [
      {
        code: "three",
        name: "four",
        position: 1,
        cards: [
          {
            title: "five",
            id: "six"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        code: "seven",
        name: "eight",
        position: 2,
        cards: [
          {
            title: "nine",
            id: "ten"
          }
        ]
      },
      //...
      {
        code: "alpha",
        name: "beta",
        position: 12,
        cards: [
          {
            title: "gamma",
            id: "theta"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

now i get another value from API, like below

```js
const newWid = {
  code: "new",
  name: "newname",
  position: 2,
  cards: [
    {
      title: "newtile",
      id: "newid"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I change `data` : only **cards** inside object inside array `wid` to be replaced at position provided in new wid and not the whole object inside `wid`) immutable, with the position provided. (`2` as provided in `newWid`)

Ps. I am not using setState.

Comment: *"Ps. I am not using setState"* What ***are*** you using?

Comment: just updating the state immutably

Comment: ***How*** are you "just" updating the state immutably? (Note that that's what `setState` does.)

Comment: lets forget about state, how can we update above object immutably

Answer (score 0):

const position = newWid.display //get the position

//step1 : get the object inside wid and update its cards
`const specificWid = { ...data.wid[position], cards : data.cards }`

//step2 : update wid
`const newestWid = [...data.wid] newwid.splice( position , 1 ,  specificWidget)`

//step3:
`{...data, data : {...data, wid : [...newwid] } }`